# Use `GoogleService-Info.plist` as secret during iOS build in Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, azure-devops, firebase-app-distribution

I have:

- a Flutter project
- an Azure Devops pipeline
- a Firebase account that I use for app distribution

The pipeline builds the flutter project, the pipeline distributes the installer through Firebase.

At the moment I have the `GoogleService-Info.plist` added in my project. Therefor it can be seen on github and anyone could download and use it.

[image]

I'd like to place this file in my secret files in Azure Devops and make the pipeline copy this file during the build of the IPA file.

I could make this with android but iOS is most of the times more problematic... In Android I could simply just copy the given file to given location and it works.

I wonder if iOS would work the same? Or it needs to use xcode to make some file linkings in the project...?

In my pipeline.yaml file I have the following for the Android part and it works perfectly:

```
             - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
               enabled: true
               name: google_services
               inputs:
                 secureFile: google-services.json
                 
             - script: |
                 cp "$(google_services.secureFilePath)" "$(googleServicesLocation)"
               displayName: 'Copy google-services.json'
               enabled: true
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it was straight forward on our pipeline, you can use the secret file and copy it to "ios/Runner" folder. Nothing fancy as I remember.

Comment: The information in the file can quite easily be extracted from the app as well. There isn't anything very secret in the file..

Comment: E.g. database must (should) be secured by rules. Consider the google service file as public.